# Run terminal and command through xCode

Tags: c, xcode, bash, macos, terminal

I basically want to write a code that will open terminal on my Mac and run a program. I copied the Terminal application where the executable for the code is.
Then I tried:

```
int system(const char *command);

system("open -a Terminal.app --args gnuplot");
```

This will open terminal but not nothing more (does not initialize GNUplot).

Thank you!

Comment: Is Terminal.app supposed to take arguments and execute them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748038/how-to-run-a-command-in-terminal-from-my-cocoa-app

Comment: Yes, exactly. @dg99

Answer (score 0):

OP here. I found out the best way to go about this is instead make a .sh file. Within that, I run my code that outputs a data file, and then, within that same .sh file, I run GNUplot how I'd like. It works much better and it automated from terminal instead of trying to make a C code to run terminal.